# What's wrong with this Java code for Android?

Tags: java, android, image-manipulation

I have written this piece of code to break an image into 9 pieces and it gives me runtime error. There is no error in LogCat and I am stuck. The error comes at line 7 line from bottom (Bitmap.createBitmap(...);).

```
public Bitmap[] getPieces(Bitmap bmp) {
        Bitmap[] bmps = new Bitmap[9];

        int width = bmp.getWidth();
        int height = bmp.getHeight();

        int rows = 3;
        int cols = 3;

        int cellHeight = height / rows;
        int cellWidth = width / cols;

        int piece = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x <= width; x += cellWidth) {
            for (int y = 0; y <= height; y += cellHeight) {
                Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, x, y, cellWidth,
                        cellHeight, null, false);
                bmps[piece] = b;
                piece++;
            }
        }

        return bmps;
    }
```

Comment: I mentioned there is no error in LogCat it seems error is in android.jar

Comment: So what's the error in android.jar?

Answer (score 4):

It is a limitation of android framework which doesn't give proper error message. The ideal solution would be to wrap your code in try / catch block and log the exception to console and fix your code accordingly, but use it only for debugging purposes.

```
try {
    // Code
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE:"+e.toString());
}
```

The above code extracted from here:

http://moazzam-khan.com/blog/?p=41

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
    for (int x = 0; x <= width; x += cellWidth) {
        for (int y = 0; y <= height; y += cellHeight) {
```

use

```
    for (int x = 0; x+cellWidth < width; x += cellWidth) {
        for (int y = 0; y+cellHeight < height; y += cellHeight) {
```

to avoid fetching parts of the image that (at least partly) don't exist.

Comment: I modified it according to your guide but still gives error. It looks the error is in android.jar and it says "Source not found".

Comment: piece can still go out of bounds of bmps.  You either need to make the bottom and right pieces bigger or drop the extra.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, piece can be greater than 8, so you are getting index out of bounds on bmps.  You need to rewrite it so that the right-most and bottom-most pieces just have all of the extra and aren't necessarily the same size.

Or, if you need them to be the same size, drop the extra rows/cols.  To make sure, I would formulate my for loop like this

```
   for (int cellX = 0; cellX < 3; cellX++) {
        int x = cellX * cellWidth;
        for (int cellY = 0; cellY < 3; cellY++) {
               int y = cellY * cellHeight;
               // find the cellWidth/Height that doesn't overflow the original image
               Bitmap b = // get the bitmap

               bmps[piece] = b;
               piece++;
        }
   }
```